# multibyte-character support for rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Java supports multi-byte character as the Japanese, Korean or Chinese.
This means that `length()` method of `java.lang.String` class returns
number of the character, not number of bytes.
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_length#Java

```
java.lang.String tmp1 = "robot";
System.out.println(tmp1.length());           -> 5
System.out.println(tmp1.getBytes().length);  -> 5
java.lang.String tmp2 = "ロボット";
System.out.println(tmp2.length());           -> 4
System.out.println(tmp2.getBytes().length);  ->12
```

Thus, using Japanese in Talker.java in rosjava_tutorial_pubsub crushes as following errors

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:165)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:813)
at org.ros.message.Message$Serialization.writeString(Unknown Source)
at org.ros.message.std_msgs.String.serialize(Unknown Source)
at org.ros.message.Message.serialize(Unknown Source)
```

My solution is to change String.java as followings but not confident since I'm not Java programmer.

```
public int serializationLength() {
   int __l = 0;
   //__l += 4 + data.length();
   __l += 4 + data.getBytes().length;
   return __l;
}
```

download attached file and rename .jpg to to .tgz
[multichar_pubsub.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13189378643720173.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11527/multibyte-character-support-for-rosjava/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-10-13**:
rospy have same problem. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_length#Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report.  I will try and get this patched soon.

What is your recommendation for rospy?  For performance reasons, rospy does not do any transformation on strings inside of messsages.  Generally, the safe policy is to always encode your strings as utf-8 before serialization.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-18**:
No longer sufficient to discuss here, moved to ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3713

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-10-17**:
check talker.py in the attached file
length=len(_x); buff.write(struct.pack('<I%ss'%length,length,_x))
or
length=len(_x.encode('utf-8','ignore'));buff.write(struct.pack('<I%ss'%length,length,_x.encode('utf-8','ignore'))
works, I'm not python programmer so it may better solution